# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint but I can see the data in primary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables, tblReportNames & tblOutputData.

```
tblReportNames has a primary key based on two columns, FactorGrp and FactorCode. 


tblOutputData has a foreign key(factorGrp, factor) 
    references tblReportNames(FactorGrp, FactorCode)
```

I am trying to upload some data into tblOutputData but getting the following error message,

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_tblOutputData_tblReportNames". The conflict
>   occurred in database "myDatabase", table "dbo.tblReportNames"

So my understanding is that if I am trying to insert data into tblOutputData (lets just assume it only has the two columns factorGrp & factor) and if one of the data values going into either factorGrp or factor and does not exist in the table tblReportNames there I would get the error message above.

Maybe easier to see an example,

```
   tblReportNames

   FactorGrp           Factor
   Weather             W1
   Weather             W2
   Atmosphere          A2
   Atmosphere          A3
```

Then if I try inserting the following into tblOutputData

```
    FactorGrp        FactorCode
    Weather          W2                   this is ok
    Atmosphere       A2                   this is ok
    Weather          W9                   this would throw the error above
    Wea              W1                   this would throw the error above
```

So what I don't understand is that every value in my real life i.e. the values I'm inserting into tblOutputData(factorGrp, factor) already exist in tblReportNames. I have put the data into excel and done vlookup's etc.

Is there any other reason I would see this error message?

Comment: You're aware that Weather / A2 would fail? Or is your question *why* it would fail?

Comment: yes I know that it would fail. I'm trying to understand that if every combination i.e. FactorGrp & Factor already exist in my tblReportNames why I'm seeing this error to do with conflicted with FOREIGN KEY constraint

Comment: Because a foreign key means that all the values in the key MUST be in the other table on the SAME row. Why do you think Weather / W9 should be valid? There isn't even a W9 on any row in the ReportNames table. Same with Wea / W1. They fail because they violate the foreign key.

Comment: I found the error Matlab 2018 (just upgraded) converts numbers in a cell matrix back to a number when uploading to SQL, Matlab 2013 didn't do this conversion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An FK relates a row in a table (OutputData) to a row in another table (ReportNames). It allows many rows in OutputData to relate to one row in ReportData.

When I say 'one row' I mean it. If Weather / A2 were allowed it would relate to multiple rows in the 'parent' table (ReportData) which is not what an FK is for.

Think of an Ordering System with an Order table, one row for each order with a PK of OrderId. Each order can be for multiple products. Each Product for the order goes into an OrderLine table; this tanle has a PK OrderLineId and it also has the OrderId as an FK to the Order table. This allows he order to find it's lines, and for each line to find it's order.

Another way to put it is that the 'Parent' part of the FK should be the PK of the parent table and *that PK must exist*.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two suggestions to consider.

1) Do all column names match in a case sensitive manner on the table and foreign key definitions? I noticed that "FactorGrp" is also referenced as "factorGrp". Column name case variances could cause a problem for bulk inserts.

2) Are you working with varchar type columns that may have trailing space characters? To check this, you may want to examine the existing table data using the LEN function to ensure the reported length matches the viewed length. Can you also check the data being inserted?